# Excel formula statement with * wildcard

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to add a couple of wildcards to an excel formula (so the formula will return true if the LOCATION is anywhere in the UK and the COURSE is any STEM course).  However I think I've got the wildcard syntax wrong as the below is returning FALSE when I'd hope it would return TRUE.

[image]

Comment: Does the location always *begin* with "UK"? Similar for course? If so, I'd suggest using `LEFT` instead of your wildcard approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few formula that allow wildcards, `AND()` is not one of them.  You will need to use SEARCH

```
=AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("UK",C6)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("STEM",D6)))
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @BigBen, `Left()` is indeed a good solution:

```
=AND(LEFT(C6;LEN("UK"))="UK";LEFT(D6;LEN("STEM"))="STEM")
```

For your information, this is the trick to know if a cell starts with "UK":

```
LEFT(C6;LEN("UK"))="UK"
// Take the length of "UK", and take that many characters from cell C6.
// Check if those equal "UK".
```